# How to avoid multiple error message while using ValidatorCalloutExtender with any Validation control?

Tags: ajaxcontroltoolkit

when we use any validator over any control and add a ajax control (ValidatorCalloutExtender) over the validator then we need to give targetID as the ID of validator. In such situation we get same error message in the extender as well in validator. How to avoid this multiple error message.

Answer (score 3):

I guess you already found out, but here's the answer anyway:

Set the property Display="None" in the validator when you use a ValidatorCalloutExtender.